# Is it possible to create a custom form in Camunda BPM changing "on-the-fly" without re-deploy?

Tags: java, angularjs, jsf, camunda, camunda-modeler

I'm new to Camunda and still trying to figure out what things are possible.

Camunda BPM provides at least three ways to create custom forms:

1. Web-based form using AngularJS https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/sdk-js/browser-forms-angular
2. Web-based form using JSF https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/bpmn-model-api/generate-jsf-form
3. Embedded task form using several mechanisms https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/usertask

I suppose I can customize a form any of those ways, but I wonder if I can create "on-the-fly" customization based on a pre-defined template stored in a database.

For example, I have a process of handling customer requests. They usually want something from three categories: A, B, and C.

FormA, FormB, and FormC are different but having typical fields for those kinds of requests.

Is there any way to add FormD in Camunda without re-deploy and changing source code of the task/process?

I mean just add a template of FormD in the database and see changes on the next process start.

Best regards, Ivan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bundle process models and custom html template in a deployment and hot deploy it together. No server restart required.
You can do this via Cockpit (if EE) or REST API:
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/develop/reference/rest/deployment/

Answer (score -1):

One possible way to do that is through custom form builder using external service form.io - https://forum.camunda.org/t/form-builder-drag-and-drop-form-server-validations/1092/14

Based on the answer from Camunda BPM forum: https://forum.camunda.org/t/is-it-possible-to-create-on-the-fly-changing-form/20683

So, theoretically it's achievable I assume.